# My Program is crashing

Tags: c, crash, queue

my program is crashing and I don't know why. I am trying to just create a queue of 10 elements. My main code:

```
#include "queue.h"

int main(void){

Queue * queue;

queue = create_q(10);
return 0;
}
```

My queue.h code:

```
#ifndef QUEUE_H_
#define QUEUE_H_
#endif /* QUEUE_H_ */

#include <stdbool.h> /* for bool type */
#include <stdio.h> /* for standard IO support */
#include <stdlib.h> /* for malloc() and free() functions */

typedef struct patient { /* my structure */
    char name [20];
    char surname [20];
    int priority;
    struct patient * next; /* pointer to next node */
}Node;

typedef struct queue {
    Node * head;
    Node * last;
}Queue;

Queue * create_q(int size);
```

My queue.c code:

```
#include "queue.h"

Queue * create_q(int size){

Node * temp, * temp2;
Queue * new ;
int i=0,j;

temp = (Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node));
new->head = temp;
if(temp == NULL){
    printf("There is not enough memory to create the %dth Node of your queue",i);
    for (j=1; j<=i; j++){
        new->head = temp->next;
        free(temp);
    }
    return NULL;
}
if (temp != NULL){
    new->head = temp;
    for (i=1; i<size; i++){
        temp2 = (Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node));
        temp->next = temp2;
    }
    return new;
}
return 0;
}
```

Using the Eclipse debugger, it seems to be crashing at new->head = temp. Hopefully someone can find my error as I can't.

Comment: You never allocated space for `new`.

Comment: are you using gcc or g++ to compile this?

Comment: @hyades Has to be gcc. g++ would likely barf on a variable named `new`, since that's a C++ keyword.

Comment: this line: 'int main(void){' should be: 'int main(){'

Comment: this line: '#endif /* QUEUE_H_ */' should be at the END of the header file, not the third line in the header file

Comment: this line: 'Queue * new ;'  'new' is a C++ keyword and your using a compiler that recognizes C++, so you should change 'new' to something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You never allocated the new Queue. You need:

```
Queue *new = malloc(sizeof(Queue));
```

Comment: @user3540561 do you know how to accept an answer? accept this one please. It's correct.